# Generate counts of users per payments given payments per user

Tags: sql, postgresql, cumulative-sum

I have the following sample data:

| product | payments | instances |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Professional | 3 | 1 |
| Professional | 4 | 1 |
| Starter | 1 | 29 |
| Starter | 2 | 8 |
| Starter | 3 | 4 |
| Team | 1 | 1 |
| Team | 2 | 2 |

whereas:

- "*instances*" stands for users
- "*product*" stands for made plans
- "*payments*" are just occurred payments

I need to transform this from a count of users who have made X payments to the amount of users that made X payments.

Expected result:

| product | payments | instances |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Professional | 1 | 2 |
| Professional | 2 | 2 |
| Professional | 3 | 2 |
| Professional | 4 | 1 |
| Starter | 1 | 41 |
| Starter | 2 | 12 |
| Starter | 3 | 4 |
| Starter | 4 | 0 |
| Team | 1 | 3 |
| Team | 2 | 2 |
| Team | 3 | 0 |
| Team | 4 | 0 |

The difference is that now, users who have made (for example) 2 payments are also counted within the number of users who have made one payment. Because logically, if you've made 2 payments, you've also made at least one payment.

Here's where I'm at:

```
with pay_counts as (
    {{#102}}
),
plan_pay_counts as (
    select
        plan,
        payments,
        count(plan) as number_of_users
    from 
        pay_counts
    group by
        plan, payments
),
i as (
    SELECT 
        generate_series(1,max(payments)) as payments
    FROM 
        pay_counts
)
select * from plan_pay_counts
order by plan, payments;
```

In theory, `i` will be the column expressing the number of payments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An optional way of approaching this problem is by:

- selecting unique products
- generating series of possible amounts for payments
- left-joining the combination of products and payments, with your original table, on matching products and payments
- computing a reversed running sum of instances, from the highest payment to the lowest, for each product partition

```
WITH products AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT product FROM tab
), payments AS (
    SELECT payment
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, (SELECT MAX(payments) FROM tab)) AS payment 
)
SELECT p1.product,
       p2.payment,
       COALESCE(SUM(tab.instances) OVER(PARTITION BY p1.product 
                                        ORDER     BY p2.payment DESC), 0) AS instances
FROM       products p1
CROSS JOIN payments p2
LEFT JOIN tab 
       ON p1.product = tab.product 
      AND p2.payment = tab.payments
ORDER BY product, payment
```

**Output**:

| product | payment | instances |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Professional | 1 | 2 |
| Professional | 2 | 2 |
| Professional | 3 | 2 |
| Professional | 4 | 1 |
| Starter | 1 | 41 |
| Starter | 2 | 12 |
| Starter | 3 | 4 |
| Starter | 4 | 0 |
| Team | 1 | 3 |
| Team | 2 | 2 |
| Team | 3 | 0 |
| Team | 4 | 0 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mNKnqLPKnCtxbSdnXdDHBQ/0).

Answer (score 0):

Going to answer my own question here. I achieved the desired result by using cross-join so that I can perform the calculation on each row and then re-group. Using the following:

```
with pay_counts as (
    {{#102}}
),
plan_pay_counts as (
    select
        plan,
        payments,
        count(plan) as number_of_users
    from 
        pay_counts
    group by
        plan, payments
),
i as (
    SELECT 
        generate_series(1,max(payments)) as payments
    FROM 
        pay_counts
),
long_form as (
    select 
        plan,
        i.payments as index_payments,
        sum(case when ppc.payments >= i.payments then number_of_users else 0 end) as number_of_users
    from 
        plan_pay_counts ppc cross join i
    group by
        plan, i.payments, ppc.payments
    order by 
        plan, i.payments, ppc.payments
)
select
    plan,
    index_payments as payments,
    sum(number_of_users) as number_of_users
from
    long_form
group by
    plan, index_payments
```